# Hiding crucial data from an SVG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a SVG generated map for the game I am developing. I have no problems with the game being open-source and it uses open web technologies such as HTML and SVG. No problems there.

But at the same time I want the players not to be able to see or reverse engineer a map of the whole world (to retain true exploration). For now I generate map using a seed that is secret and not version controlled. So even though the algorithm is known curious players can use open-sourced code to generate "game-like worlds" but not that exact one. This solves the "global" problem.

But since SVG is rendered on a page as a single Voronoi diagram all the data (I don't mind the coordinates of points) would be extractable. Data like resources, land types, biomes, climate etc. could be fetched from SVG to gain an upper hand in finding good locations for settlements.

Any idea how to prevent that? Players have limited vision so I thought about either:

- not rendering the whole Voronoi diagram at all (just the visible part), but that could be potentially tricky to do (maybe, haven't looked into it yet),
- inserting the resource/land tile data into SVG graph only to visible locations

I can see the benefits of both approaches and if done correctly it could even boost the performance (not rendering the whole thing/rendering with less data) and lead to bigger worlds without impacting performance.

Any other ideas/programming/architectural approaches to help with the issue?

(I am using Vue.js, d3.js, svg-pan-zoom and Laravel backend just in case it helps.)

Comment: It sounds like you're onto something with only doing partial rendering base on the user current coordinates in the game world.  In 3D game programming we often partially render using a technique called quad trees, maybe you could do something similar here?  You could store the bare minimum parameters of the world such as its max x/y values so that you can map the players current position within a tree and then render to the canvas based on their current position in the tree.

Comment: As an aside to my first comment, if you don't want all assets downloaded to the client in one go, you could do some sort of progressive rendering...as the user traverses further through the world (and becomes deeper or higher in the tree) then you can start progresssively serving those assets to update your canvas with.  This will also reduce your initial load time, but be aware it will also have drawbacks if the player is on a slow connection - there are bound to be bottle-necks but its certainly possible

Comment: @Alex I managed to implement it by mathematically finding two level deep neighbours of the voronoi cell user currently is in and rendering only those on the screen (which improved performance greatly as well). I hid them from user and placed a circular render zone around the player to create an "area of sight". Also progressive rendering is the way to go as the game is very slow paced and traveling takes literally hours and days in real life. No one has Internet THAT slow. :) It's a great compromise. Sorry for long reply but if you could reformat your comment as an answer I would accept it.

Comment: I'm glad that helped I'll write an answer after work.  do you mind if I ask what the game is called? I'm a die hard fan of the civ series, your game sounds awesome!

Comment: It's not even named yet. :) We just have a bunch of prototyped systems like map or inventory but we are yet to do something bigger from it. But it's more similiar to role-playing games and society simulators with world exploration than Civ series as players are controlling characters, not civilizations. Anyway, your help was greatly appreciated as it pushed us in the right direction. :)

Comment: Sounds really interesting, shoot me a message when you guys are further into dev and have something playable, sounds like my sort of genre! I'm glad I could help, all the best to you and your team :)

Answer (score -2):

The ideas that you gave are perfect, but for implementing them, you need to make hard work, and spend much time.

I have a suggestion. Is will work for most of the users. Maybe some users will "hack" it. But I believe it will work for 95% of the times.

You can create a very big rectangle, from the top left point 0,0 until the right bottom point. The rectangle will be white, and it will be over all other shapes.

This way if someone will download the SVG, we will see nothing. Just a big white rectangle.

In you game HTML, you can add a CSS selector, to hide this rectangle.

If you following this method, most of the users (who don't have a photo editing software) will not be able to see the map.

Users who knows how to inspect elements in HTML may see the map. But I believe that most of them who will see a white box, will not believe that there is something behind.

I think that this is a simple temporary approach that you can do, before doing other more defensive ways.